# Date parameters returning values outside the range of dates

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Using SQL Server Management Studio, I have a query that I'm using date parameters but when I execute the query, I see rows that aren't in the date range selected.

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '7/10/2017'
DECLARE @EndDate Date = '7/17/2017'

SELECT DISTINCT 
    PROJECTID, 
    ACTIVITYID, ACTIVITYNAME, 
    ISPRIMARYRESOURCE, RESOURCEID,
    STARTDATE, FINISHDATE,
    FORMAT(STARTDATE,'dddd') + ', ' + FORMAT(STARTDATE,'m') + ', ' +  
    FORMAT(STARTDATE,'yyyy') AS ES_FORMATTED
FROM 
    Primavera_ODS.TASKRSRCX
WHERE 
    PROJECTID IN ('ONLINE', 'ESR01', 'H-ONL-Active', 'HNP-NBKRRPLD', 'HNP-RVH-LIV',
                  'HNP-CSCR-LIV', 'HNP-TCS-LIV', 'HNP-LPT-LIV', 'HNP-DICSP-LIV',
                  'HNP-NRRVHE', 'HNP-IDS-LIV')
    AND FINISHDATE >= @StartDate 
    AND STARTDATE < @EndDate
ORDER BY 
    STARTDATE
```

The `STARTDATE` and `FINISHDATE` fields are formatted as datetime.

When the query is executed, the first row is showing a STARTDATE of 2012-11-01 08:00:00.000 and a FINISHDATE of 2018-09-27 17:00:00.000. Clearly not in the date range declared.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].  "Minimal" means strip away the parts that are irrelevant, like all the `PROJECTID`-related nonsense.  "Verifiable" means include `CREATE TABLE` statement and sample data (in the from of `INSERT INTO` statements) so that we can see exactly what unexpected results your query yields.

Comment: It's good practice to show if these answers have helped resolve your problem and in what way they did.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '7/10/2017'
```

Is this 7th October 2017 or 10th July 2017?

Either way

```
FINISHDATE >=@StartDate and STARTDATE < @EndDate
```

means

```
'2018-09-27' >= '2017-07-10' AND '2012-11-01' < '2017-07-17'
```

Both conditions are true

Do you mean this?

```
STARTDATE < @StartDate AND @EndDate <= FINISHDATE
```

Comment: It's July 10th and July 17th. So how would I write the query to get data within the selected range?

Comment: See Peter Smith's and my answers below respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test both dates lie within the bounds so:

```
@StartDate BETWEEN STARTDATE  AND FINISHDATE 
AND
@EndDate  BETWEEN STARTDATE  AND FINISHDATE
```

You may also need:

```
AND
@StartDate < @EndDate
```

You can also write your dates as `'17-July-2017'` or `'2017-07-17'` to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL is as per above, then nothing is wrong.

Your criteria is that `FINISHDATE >= @StartDate` and `@StartDate` is '7/10/2017'. From the result you get of `FINISHDATE` = '2018-09-27 17:00:00.000', so clearly `FINISHDATE` > `@startDate`.

The criteria also say that `STARTDATE < @EndDate`. `@EndDate` is set to '7/17/2017' and you get back `STARTDATE` = '2012-11-01 08:00:00.000 ', which is true.

My assumption is that your date range should be between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`? If that is correct maybe you could try something like:

```
AND 
FINISHDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND
STARTDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Niels

Answer (score 0):

You were exactly right gbn. I've accepted the query parameter and results were returning the data as requested.